# authenticated through LemonLDAP::NG in openerp

Tags: authentication, odoo, ldap

I try to find some like this https://www.dokuwiki.org/auth:lemonldap but for OpenERP.

Please tell me how I can do this for OpenERP

Comment: I know nothing about OpenERP, but it supports LDAP authentication; have you tried https://www.openerp.com/apps/auth_ldap/ ?

Answer (score 1):

They released a module for OpenERP 7.0 and LemonLDAP 1.3.1.
Here you go: https://github.com/trobz/openerp-auth-lemonldap

Cheers!